# How to Redirect back to the failed Resource after successful authentication with Auth0

Tags: auth0, react-admin

When unauthenticated user trying to access Resource the `authProvider` function is called with `FETCH_ERROR` type:

```
if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
    const { status } = params;
    if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
        return Promise.reject();
    }
}
```

Status 401 or 403 triggering the `authProvider()` with `AUTH_LOGOUT` type and then redirection to `/login` page.

The login page calls the `auth0-js.authorize()` method, which redirects to the auth0 authentication page and, after authentication, redirects back to the login page.

Which is the right way to do redirect back to failed Resource after successful authentication on login page?

`userLogin(payload, pathName)` is called, but how to restore path to failed Resource?

Should it be saved to localStorage on AUTH_ERROR?

Comment: Hi Alexey, I'm trying to get auth0 to work with my react-admin application at the moment. Is your code available somewhere I could take a look at? My auth0 flow is working but I can't seem to get my react-admin customRoutes to pick up the /callback route in order for me to handleAuthentication.

Comment: Hi Will, I do not remember details, but you could take a look: [merge-admin](https://github.com/alexicum/merge-admin)

Comment: That was super helpful. Thanks Alexey, using the standard /login route instead of trying to create my own /callback route worked. I also needed the historyWrapper you had but it is all working perfectly now.

Comment: Great! I am happy that it was helpful for you!